# Can karma be destroyed by other Niyamas?

Tags: karma

Can karma be destroyed by other Niyamas?

Can the other four niyamas from the "Five Niyamas" remove a person's karma? Or just affect it?

Comment: What are the Five Niyamas? Thanks

Comment: From what i understand they are 5 "laws" of the world  -  the law of karma is one of them 

I understand that not all agree about that there are 5 laws and some say there is only karma  ----  i personally dont like it and would love to think that all is kamma and that's it ...

a link i didnt read even about this thing :  http://thezenuniverse.org/the-five-nyamas/

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. But linking this question here as some of the answers there shed some light on to this question. https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/25790/is-there-a-way-to-hasten-the-results-of-bad-deeds/25793#25793

Answer (score 1):

No, if speaking of "can one deed make another undone" ([MN 101](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.101.than_en.html)), Breath, but by the deed of traing the mind, one can reach the ability to bear results of fruits from deeds easier. See the [The Salt Crystal](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than_en.html).

Since it has much impact of general ways of thinking, living mostly in a world of believe that unrightouseness could be corrected, the Essay [Wisdom over Justice](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/wisdomoverjustice_en.html) might give certain inspiration, dealing at least with this issue outwardly.

For Suttas (teachings) on *kamma* (actions) look up here: [Kamma](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-subject_en.html#kamma)

In detail, of what certain sects see as skillful (here *Niyamas*), there are certainly deeds which are not benefical at all for even lighten effects of old kamma, not to speak of going beyound. But such would need the discussiin of each of this practices. Some of this classical are benefical, *kusala-kamma*.

To get rid of the effects of ones previous deeds eternally, there is just one refuge: Nibbana.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purposes or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange]*

Answer (score 0):

They can influence Karma and affect Vipaka(result).
ex: The reason why mangoes taste the way they taste is due to Bija Niyama & Uttu Niyama. Not because of Karma. So when you eat a mango, the pleasurable feeling at the tongue arises due to Karma. But Karma cannot make it taste like an apple, if you eat a mango. The nature of the pleasure is conditioned by other Niyamas.

Similarly, they could potentially make some Karma defunct(Ahosi) by not giving them the chance to come into fruition. 
ex: When the world system is about to be destroyed, if you do a Karma that can only give result in the sensual realm, it could become defunct due to the destruction of the sensual realm.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66994/discussion-on-answer-by-sankha-kulathantille-can-karma-be-destroyed-by-other-niy).

Answer (score 0):

Kamma is destroyed only by the Dhamma Niyama of not-self (*anatta*).

> *Just this noble eightfold path — right view, right resolve, right
>   speech, right action, right livelihood, right effort, right
>   mindfulness, right concentration — is the path of practice leading to
>   the cessation of kamma. AN 6.63*

Comment: thanks for the reply i would like to think you are right but i want to be sure its the case  ... so devils advocate :  what you wrote talks about the complete cessation of karma in genral  and that the noble eightfold path is the only way to do so  .... but that doesn't mean that spesific karmas along the way cannot be destroyed by other laws (from the five niyamas)  .......  just for the ultimate cessation of karma you can only do it with the path - but that is a different issue