# Is there a way to speed up the extinguishment of bad karma?

Tags: theravada, karma

If you are in a situation/or period of your life, where you think your are reaping the results of bad karma, is there something you can do to mitigate or hasten the results of such bad karma since you can't avoid it?

Comment: There may already be some answers to this topic, at [Is there a way to hasten the results of bad deeds](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25790/254)

Comment: If you are not satisfied with existing answers, please ask a more specific follow-up question.

Comment: https://lifeisauspicious.com/2016/06/18/mythstruths-about-karma/